# google firebase cloud functions + firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to get data from firebase firestore inside my firebase cloud functions, my index.js looks like this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const db = admin.firestore();
exports.writeReport = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    var fetchedData;

    db.collection("mycollection").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            fetchedData = doc.id;
            console.log("data" + `${doc.id} => ${doc.data()}`);
        });
    });
    response.send("data " + fetchedData);
});
```

This code gives me an output of "data undefined" so I guess this means that the foreach statement doesn't get executed.
I am new to google cloud so I've been looking through the documentation and I can't fins anything which is related to my issue.
Thanks in advance,
Guy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`db.collection("mycollection").get()` is asynchronous and returns immediately.  The `then` callback function will get executed some time later, after the query completes.  `then()` is also asynchronous.  In fact anything that returns a promise is async.

This means that your call to `response.send()` is executing before the query completes.  The function terminates as soon as the response is sent, so the query never completes.  You need to wait for the query to complete before sending the response.  The easiest thing to do is simply call `response.send` from inside the callback.

```
db.collection("mycollection").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        fetchedData = doc.id;
        console.log("data" + `${doc.id} => ${doc.data()}`);
    });
    response.send("data " + fetchedData);
});
```

If you're new to JavaScript, I strong suggest spending time learning how promises work.  There is a [video series](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/) on learning how to use promises in Cloud Functions that you might find helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I will check out the video series. I've tried your solution, even after moving the response.send into the callback it still gives the same output. I tried to move it into the foreach but then the function just took 60s to give a response, the response was that the request was timed out.

Comment: Then there is some other error, and you should handle errors from the rejected promise returned by `then`.

Comment: Already tried it after watching one of the videos, which are actually great, thanks for producing them, but I think that I have another error, I was using pure JS and not typescript, could this be the issue?

Comment: If you have a new problem, please post a separate question explaining what's now not working the way you expect.